# How to initialize Firebase real-time database with Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I've never used Firebase before, and am trying to connect a real-time database to my Unity app. Firebase says to use this code to initialize the SDK, but I'm getting an error for CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync() that "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods". It also says ContinueWith method must have a return type, and task namespace cannot be found/doesn't exist in the current context.

I'm unsure what the comment means where is says to create and hold a reference to the FirebaseApp. Does anyone know what I would need to do to get it working with Unity?

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
// Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp, i.e.
//   app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
// where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.

// Set a flag here indicating that Firebase is ready to use by your
// application.
} else {
UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
// Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
}
});
```

Comment: What does the rest of this script look like? That error is caused by not putting your code within a class.

Comment: Hi Susan, same question; is your code inside a class? seems like is a function declared inside a Namespace but not inside a class.